# How to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the value * for my ajax requests to the API?

Tags: ajax, spring-boot

I have an API and I would like to consume it within a bootstrap template with AJAX. But when I try it, the following error appears : `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/authenticate' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`
I saw in my researches I have to allow it in my Spring Boot API, what I did by adding this line in swagger config:

```java
        @Bean
        public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        // Allow anyone and anything access. Probably ok for Swagger spec
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/v2/api-docs", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);

        }
```

despite this adding, the response is the  error i mentioned before.
what i could add is this error is appearing near my `DOCTYPE HTML` tag.
here is the API call code:

```java
function getAuthToken(){
       var token='';
       var req1= new XMLHttpRequest(); 
       req1.open("POST","http://localhost:8080/authenticate",true);
       if(token=''){
       req1.setRequestHeader('Accept','Application/json; charset=utf-8');
       req1.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','Application/json; charset=utf-8');
       req1.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
       }else{
        req1.setRequestHeader('Accept','Application/json; charset=utf-8');
        req1.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','Application/json; charset=utf-8');
        req1.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer' +''+token);
         req1.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');

        }
        req1.send(credentials);
        console.log(req1.response.data);
        return req1.status;
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the request and the api call?

Comment: @Ramses Issue is with the CORS setup in your Spring boot app. You are creating CORS filter but not assigning it to FilterRegistrationBean

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with your CORS configuration in the Spring Boot App. Making some changes in the CORS configurations.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
config.setAllowCredentials(true);
config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
config.addAllowedHeader("*");
config.addAllowedMethod("*");
source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(0);
return filterRegistrationBean ;
}
```

The line  `source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config)` will allow access to all the API endpoints in your app (basically whitelisting all the URL). You can also whitelist specific url by replacing `/**` with the actual url `/authenticate`

`

Comment: @ramses-kouam if was able to solve your problem, pls do upvote and accept the same.Thank you :)